# Проблемы с калькулятором

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

написал второе приложение,но не нажимаются кнопки,помогите

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Калькулятор')

#Логика калькулятора
def calc(key):
  global memory
  if key =='=':
    #исключаем написание букв
    strl ='-+0123456789.*/'
    if calc_entry.get()[0] not in strl:
        calc_entry.insert(END,"Первый символ не число!")
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка!','Вы ввели не число')
    #Счёт
    try:
        result = eval(calc_entry.get())
        calc_entry.insert(END,'=' + str(result) )
    except:
        calc_entry.insert(END, 'Ошибка!')
        messagebox.showerror('Проверь правильность данных')
    #Clean
  elif key == 'C':
    calc_entry.delete(0,END)
    #from + to -
  elif key == '-/+':
    if '=' in calc_entry.get():
        calc_entry.delete (0, END)
    try:
      if calc_entry.get()[0] == '-':
          calc_entry.delete(0)
      else:
        calc_entry.insert(0,'-')
    except IndexError:
      pass
  else:
    if '=' == calc_entry.get():
            calc_entry.delete(0,END)
            calc_entry.insert(END,key)




#Add btth
btth_list = [
  '7','8','9','+','-',
  '4','5','6','*','/',
  '1','2','3','-/+','=',
  '0','.','C'
]
r = 1
c = 0

for i in btth_list:
  rel = ''
  cmd=lambda x=i: calc(x)
  ttk.Button(root, text=i, command=cmd).grid(row=r,column=c)
  c += 1
  if c>4:
    c=0
    r += 1

calc_entry=Entry (root, width=33)
calc_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: наверное проблема в лямде. при вызове cmd без аргумента получается фигня. и с аргументом тоже там будет всегда 'с'

Comment: и что делать???

Comment: простите у меня нет компьютера чтоб протестировать и дать полноценный ответ с кодом

Comment: Кнопки не нажимаются, потому что в функции calc нет реакции на нажатие цифровых кнопок.

Comment: а какую тогда функию можно придумать

Comment: ну или как исправить

Comment: @Никита 1 - проверять, что нажата кнопка с цифрой, 2 - при нажатии на кнопку с цифрой добавлять эту цифру в текстовое поле.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [tkinter error памагите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156968/tkinter-error-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Я смог решить проблему, ниже верный код

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
root = Tk()
root.title('Калькулятор')
button_list=[]
#Логика калькулятора
def calc(key):
           
  global memory
  
  if key =='=':
    #исключаем написание букв
    strl ='-+0123456789.*/'
    if calc_entry.get()[0] not in strl:
        calc_entry.insert(END,"Первый символ не число!")
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка!','Вы ввели не число')
    #Счёт
    try:
        result = eval(calc_entry.get()[0:len(calc_entry.get())])
        calc_entry.insert(END,'=' + str(result) )
    except:
        calc_entry.insert(END, 'Ошибка!')
        messagebox.showerror('Проверь правильность данных')
    #Clean
  elif key == 'C':
    calc_entry.delete(0,END)
    #from + to -
  elif key == '-/+':
    if '=' in calc_entry.get():
        calc_entry.delete (0, END)
    try:
      if calc_entry.get()[0] == '-':
          calc_entry.delete(0)
      else:
        calc_entry.insert(0,'-')
    except IndexError:
      pass
  else:
           calc_entry.insert(END,key)




#Add btth
btth_list = [
  '7','8','9','+','-',
  '4','5','6','*','/',
  '1','2','3','-/+','=',
  '0','.','C'
]
r = 1
c = 0

for i in btth_list:
  rel = ''
  button_list.append(ttk.Button(root, text=i, command=partial(calc,i)).grid(row=r,column=c))
  c += 1
  if c>4:
    c=0
    r += 1

calc_entry=Entry (root, width=33)
calc_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

root.mainloop()
```